# How to show tags in my tumblr theme?

Tags: css, tags, themes, tumblr

I just installed [this](http://yukoki.tumblr.com/post/56626249026/theme-26-hotaru-by-yukoki-live) theme and I've been trying to get it to show my tags.

I've tried adding the code to show tags, and while it will show them, it totally messes up the format of the theme. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be much appreciated! Thanks (:

Comment: Please provide some code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the [Customize](http://www.tumblr.com/customize) section after you log in
2. Click on the **Theme** tab
3. Click **Use custom HTML**

This will bring up a edit box that contains the HTML and tumblr code used by the theme.

Put the code for the tags somewhere between the opening `{block:Posts}` and closing `{/block:Posts}` tags.

To start off easy, let's put the tags at the bottom of all your post types.

Where you see the following line:

```
{/block:Posts}
```

Insert the following starting chunk to look like this:

```
     {block:HasTags}
           {block:Tags}
              <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
           {/block:Tags}
        {/block:HasTags}

{/block:Posts}
```

1. Click **Update preview** in the lower right corner of the edit box (or
   it will update itself)
2. Click **Save + Close** in the upper right of the dashboard.

Refresh your tumblr blog and you should now see the tags display.

You can read more of the specific tags markup needed on the Tags section of ["Creating a custom HTML theme"](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags)